# Form in asp.net webform content page

Tags: css, asp.net, forms

I have  a project, i have used form elemen in master page.

In the content page, i have css class for bootstrap form-horizontal, form-group, and i place a button in the form-group and form-horizontal class.
When i press the button, it doesn't fire at all.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-8" style="float: right;">
<asp:Button ID="btn_simpan_user" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Simpan" OnClick="btn_simpan_user_Click" />
</div>
</div>
```

I make other button in another webform pages in the same solution with the same master page, but **without form-group and form-horizontal**. It works, it can fire.

```
<asp:Button ID="button_test" runat="server" OnClick="btn_test" Text="Test" />
```

My Question is:
I know that in webform page content we can't make another form since that only one form can run in a server and it has already run on the master page. 
But  only make form-group and form -horizontal class, **is it wrong??**

what should i do to run the button? I need the form group and form-horizontal class to make my pages looking good.

Comment: you can use div `<div class="form-horizontal">`

Comment: Can you edit your code and show where form-horizontal fits in?